The method save(Iterable<S>) in the type MongoRepository<Blog,String> is not applicable for the arguments (Blog)
After following a lot of online articles about starting up a CRUD app with Java/Mongo, I am seeing this error. I did a lot of iterations, but cannot figured it out...
Blog Model

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor; 
import lombok.Data; 
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor; 
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id; 
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document; 


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "Blog")
public class Blog {
    
        @Id
        private int id;
        private String title;

}


Blog Repo

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface BlogRepository extends MongoRepository<Blog, String> {

    
}

Blog Controller (Where I get the error)

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BlogController {
    
   
   private BlogRepository blogRepo;
   
   @Autowired
   public BlogController(BlogRepository blogRepo) {
       this.blogRepo = blogRepo;
   }
   
   @PostMapping(value = "/add")
   public String addBlog(@RequestBody Blog blog){
       blogRepo.save(blog);
       return "Blog created successfully";
   }
   
   @GetMapping(value = "/get")
   public String getBlog(){
       blogRepo.findAll();
       return "Blog created successfully";
   }

}

I get it on the addBlog method:

The method save(Iterable) in the type MongoRepository<Blog,String>
is not applicable for the arguments (Blog)

My getBlog is fine. I don't know why the save method is giving me trouble. Thank you
I am trying to save this to my local mongodb repository

MongoRepository<Blog, String> - the second type parameter needs to be the type of the id of the entity the repository manages.
